# How to find what Service Pack of IE is currently installed on the system?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, service-pack

We have website and one of our customers complains that when he launches the URL there is a blank popup that appears on his window.

He uses IE 7.

We have tried to reproduce the same behaviour in our local PC's but we are not able to do so. The site opens up perfectly fine in our systems.

We suspect that it could be due to a different Service Pack installed on the customer's PC.

Is there a way we can find out which SP is he running on. What would be the simplest process which we can then pass on to the customer to know which SP is he running on?

Answer (score 3):

The service pack level isn't always enough.  You should look at the exact version number by choosing "About..." in the "Help" menu.

You should be able to find a history of updates that were installed (including Service Packs for various things) under the "Add/Remove programs" Control Panel applet (you might have to select the "Show updates" checkbox if one exists and it doesn't have a check-mark).  Please note that although many of the updates are stored in an entry that usually shows up somewhere near the bottom of the list, there are a few other updates that get sprinkled throughout, so you'll need to spend a bit of time browsing through the entire list to be sure.  This is why I recommend just dealing with the version number alone in the Help->About menu item instead.

Comment: @Randolf: Thanks! So, I will first get started with that now.

Comment: You're welcome!  Please add an update to these comments to let everyone know how this worked out for you.